# How to compare last names from two full-name strings that might include extra spaces, a middle name, or different cases?

Tags: php

I am trying to create a function that compares the last names of two strings. This is what I have so far, which generally works:

```
public function doBillingAccountLastNameMatch(  ) {
    if( sizeof( $this->getUserBillingAddress() ) ){
        $shippingUserNames  = explode( ' ', $this->getUserBillingAddress()['CustName'] );
        $userNames          = explode( ' ', $this->getUserData()['UName']  );

        if( strtolower( $shippingUserNames[ sizeof( $shippingUserNames ) - 1 ] ) == strtolower( $userNames[ sizeof( $userNames ) - 1 ] ) ){
            return CustomHelper::functionSuccessResponse();
        }else{
            return CustomHelper::functionErrorResponse( 'User Payment Data is not found' );
        }
    }else{
        return CustomHelper::functionErrorResponse( 'User Payment Data is not found' );
    }
}
```

However, there are some situations when one of the two names has an extra space in it (i.e. "John  Doe " vs "John Doe"), or might have a middle name (i.e. "John James Doe" vs "John Doe"), or might have different capitalizations (i.e. "john doe" vs "John Doe").

What's a simple and elegant way to cover all of these scenarios?

Comment: strtolower and comparing the last array element (= last name) already cover capitalization and middle names. As for extra spaces at the end of the names, just trim them before comparing. [http://php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php](http://php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If instead of exploding, `trim()` the inputs and then extract the string from the last space (using `strrpos()` to find the last occurrence and `substr()` to extract).  Then use a case insensitive compare (`strcasecmp()` 
 which returns 0 if the strings match)to compare the two strings...

```
$sName = trim($this->getUserBillingAddress()['CustName']);
$cName = trim($this->getUserData()['UName']);
$shippingUserName  = substr($sName, strrpos( $sName , ' ' )+1);
$userName          = substr($cName, strrpos( $cName , ' ' )+1);

if( strcasecmp( $shippingUserName, $userName ) === 0 ){
    return CustomHelper::functionSuccessResponse();
}
else    {
    return CustomHelper::functionErrorResponse( 'User Payment Data is not found' );
}
```